# Select Where multiple id

Tags: database, select, where-clause

```php
<?php
$con = mysql_connect('localhost', 'root', 'pass');
if(!$con){
echo "Error connection";
}
$select_db = mysql_select_db('mydatabase', $con);
if(!$select_db){
echo "Error to select database";
}
mysql_set_charset("utf8", $con);

$result = mysql_query("select count(1) FROM Credit WHERE CreditStatusID=6");
$row = mysql_fetch_array($result);

$total = $row[0]-1;
echo "<font size='6px' color='#000000'>Total:&nbsp;</font><font size='6px' color='#FF0000'><b>" . $total . "</b></font>";
mysql_close($con);
?>
```

I need to get some other information for example `WHERE CreditStatusID=6 AND CreditStatus=7,8,9,..` but it does not work. Can you explain me how can I do that in another way?

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
select count(1) FROM Credit WHERE CreditStatusID=6 and CreditStatus in (7,8,9)
```

Comment: I tried this way but no result:

$result = mysql_query("select count(1) FROM Credit WHERE CreditStatusID=6 AND CreditStatus in (1,2,3)");

Comment: No result please help :(

Comment: Can you paste your table contents in question please?

Answer (score 0):

The WHERE-clause should look like this:

```
...WHERE CreditStatusID=6 AND CreditStatus IN (7, 8 ,9);
```

instead of the array "(7,8,9)" you can also use a sub-select..